# Pusher event is triggered twice

Tags: javascript, php, events, publish-subscribe, pusher

I'm using Pusher (pusher.com) to trigger notification to all logged in clients whenever the admin sends one.

For some reason the event is shooting twice, although I only trigger it once.

Client side subscription code:

```
var handleToastrListener = function() {

     var pusher = new Pusher("913284db62a0cc237db4");
     var channel = pusher.subscribe('toastr-channel');

           channel.bind('new-toast', function(data) {

            toastr.options = data.options;
            var $toast = toastr[data.scf](data.msg, data.title);

           return true;

           });  
   }

       handleToastrListener();
```

Server side publish code (PHP using pusher package):

```
 $pusher = new Pusher(PUSHER_KEY, PUSHER_SECRET, PUSHER_APP_ID);
 $pusher->trigger('toastr-channel', 'new-toast', $input );
```

The Pusher debug console shows that only one message was received.

The pusher-js Javascript logging, however, shows two messages:

```
Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"new-toast","data":{"options":{"positionClass":"toast-top-right","onclick":"","showDuration":"1000","hideDuration":"1000","timeOut":"5000","extendedTimeOut":"1000","showEasing":"swing","hideEasing":"linear","showMethod":"fadeIn","hideMethod":"fadeOut"},"title":"Toastr Notifications","msg":"Gnome & Growl type non-blocking notifications","scf":"success"},"channel":"toastr-channel"} app.js:143
Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"new-toast","data":{"options":{"positionClass":"toast-top-right","onclick":"","showDuration":"1000","hideDuration":"1000","timeOut":"5000","extendedTimeOut":"1000","showEasing":"swing","hideEasing":"linear","showMethod":"fadeIn","hideMethod":"fadeOut"},"title":"Toastr Notifications","msg":"Gnome & Growl type non-blocking notifications","scf":"success"},"channel":"toastr-channel"}
```

looking further I found the subscription occurs twice, although I call it only once:

```
Pusher : Event sent : {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"channel":"toastr-channel"}} app.js:143
Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","data":{},"channel":"toastr-channel"} app.js:143
Pusher : No callbacks on toastr-channel for pusher:subscription_succeeded app.js:143
Pusher : State changed : connecting -> connected app.js:143
Pusher : Event sent : {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"channel":"toastr-channel"}} app.js:143
Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","data":{},"channel":"toastr-channel"} app.js:143
Pusher : No callbacks on toastr-channel for pusher:subscription_succeeded
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things you should definitely take a look at and update your question appropriately:

1. [The Pusher Debug Console](http://pusher.com/docs/debugging#pusher_debug_console) - is the event shown twice in there?
2. [pusher-js JavaScript logging](http://pusher.com/docs/debugging#pusher_logging) - is the event being logged as *incoming* twice?

The other common problem here is that sometimes events may have been bound to twice - hence, two callbacks. However, your code doesn't suggest that this is happening.

Comment: The debug console show only one message, but the logging show two. I've updated my question accordingly

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. It turns out I called the handle twice in different places in my code

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you need to unbind the channel before binding.

```
pusherClient.subscribe(1234);
pusherClient.bind(1234);
pusherClient.bind("incoming-message", (text) => {
  console.log(text);
});
```

See [here](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js#binding-to-events) for more info.